# Edit table Javascript and corresponding dates

Tags: javascript, html

I have this table:[image: table]

I'm trying to insert the events I have in my database in a certain way: basically what i would like is to let the code to check the name of the events in my database (blue square) and associate the cells (above the red line) where I add manually my events with the same name. And at that point add the hour difference (between startDate and endDate) in the corresponding day of the month.

**This is the code that render the header of my table (where it takes the current month and add every days of that month):**

```
function renderHead(div, start, end) {
        var c_year = start.getFullYear();
        var r_year = "<tr>";
        var daysInYear = 0;
    
        var c_month = start.getMonth();
        var r_month = "<tr>";
        var daysInMonth = 0;
    
        var r_days = "<tr> <td id= 'event'> Eventi </td>";
        
        for (start; start <= end; start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)) {
    
                if (start.getFullYear() !== c_year) {
                    r_year += '<td colspan="' + daysInYear + '">' + c_year + '</td>';
                    c_year = start.getFullYear();
                    daysInYear = 0;
                }
                daysInYear++;
    
                if (start.getMonth() !== c_month) {
                    r_month += '<td colspan="' + daysInMonth + '">' + months[c_month] + '</td>';
                    c_month = start.getMonth();
                    daysInMonth = 0;
                }
                daysInMonth++;
    
                r_days += '<td id="days">' + start.getDate() + '</td>'; 
        }
        
        r_days += " <td id='tot'> Totale </td> </tr>";
        r_year += '<td colspan="' + (daysInYear) + '">' + months[c_month] + ' '+ c_year +'</td>'; 
        r_year += "</tr>";
        
        table = "<table id='tblData' border='1'>" + r_year + r_days + "</table>"; 
    
        div.html(table);
    }
    var date = new Date();
    var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    renderHead($('div#table2'), new Date(firstDay), new Date(lastDay));
```

**This is the function that get the events (blue square) and the difference between startDate and endDate from my database** (and the tbody where i manually add the events):

function getEvents(year, month){

```
    var currentEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents').filter(event =\> (new Date(event.start) \> firstDay && new Date(event.end) \<= lastDay));
    
    for(i=0; i\<currentEvents.length; i++) {
        if(currentEvents\[i\].nomeUtente == $("#nomeUtente").data('value')){
            const start = new Date(currentEvents\[i\].start.\_i);
            const end = new Date(currentEvents\[i\].end.\_i);           
            if (currentEvents\[i\].title == "Normali" || currentEvents\[i\].title == "Ferie"){ 
                const milliseconds = Math.abs((end - start)-5400000);
                var hours = milliseconds / 36e5;
            }else{
                const milliseconds = Math.abs(end - start);
                var hours = milliseconds / 36e5;            
            }
            
            if ($("#tblData tbody").length == 0) {
            $("#tblData").append("\<tbody\>"+ "\<tr\>\<td id='norm'\>Normali\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='stra'\>Straordinarie\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='fer'\>Ferie\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='mal'\>Malattia\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='perm'\>Permesso\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='sm'\>Smart Working\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='tras'\>Trasferta\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='anr'\>Assenze non retribuita\</td\>\</tr\>"+
                "\<tr\>\<td id='alt'\>Altro\</td\>\</tr\>"+ "\</tbody\>");
        } 
            
            $("#tblData tbody").append("\<tr\>" +
                //"\<td\>" + currentEvents\[i\].title + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
                "\<td\>" + hours + "\</td\>" +
            "\</tr\>");
        }       
    }
};
```

For reference, this is my database: [image]

---

**This is what I've been doing so far:**

```
function getEvents(year, month){
var table = document.getElementById('tblData');
var currentEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents').filter(event => (new Date(event.start) > firstDay && new Date(event.end) <= lastDay));

for(i=0; i<currentEvents.length; i++) {
    if(currentEvents[i].nomeUtente == $("#nomeUtente").data('value')){
        const start = new Date(currentEvents[i].start._i);
        const end = new Date(currentEvents[i].end._i);          
        if (currentEvents[i].title == "Normali" || currentEvents[i].title == "Ferie"){ //provato a mettere una condizione nel quale se Normali o Ferie togliere millisecondi se no no
            const milliseconds = Math.abs((end - start)-5400000);
            var hours = milliseconds / 36e5;
        }else{
            const milliseconds = Math.abs(end - start);
            var hours = milliseconds / 36e5;            
        }
        
        if ($("#tblData tbody").length == 0) {
            $("#tblData").append("<tbody>"+ "<tr><td id='norm'>Normali</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='stra'>Straordinarie</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='fer'>Ferie</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='mal'>Malattia</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='perm'>Permesso</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='sm'>Smart Working</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='tras'>Trasferta</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='anr'>Assenze non retribuita</td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td id='alt'>Altro</td></tr>"+ "</tbody>");
        } 
        
        
        for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
            for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
                if(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML == currentEvents[i].title){ //controlla contenuto cella se è uguale ad evento
                    $("#tblData tbody #days").append("<tr> <td>" + hours + "</td></tr>");
                }else{
                    alert (table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
                }
            }
        }                   
    }
}
```

};

But it doesnt work :(